# Systems that Display Chaotic Behavior

Tags: mathematical-modeling, nonlinear-system, chaos-theory, nonlinear-analysis, nonlinear-dynamics

I take a course in 'nonlinear dynamics and chaos'.
For our final project, we have to choose a dynamical system in that is nonlinear and specifically one that displays chaotic behavior.

I know that systems, anywhere from the fields of population biology and climatology to the fields of celestial and quantum mechanics, can be chaotic.
I need a model that is mathematically concise and not too hard to understand for the layman (assuming I have no knowledge in said field).

I don't know any specific model on which to base my project and therefore
I am sharing this here with the hope of receiving interesting ideas from people who happen to know such systems and don't mind taking a few minutes to share.

Thanks in advance and happy new year to all !

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem

Comment: A classic option, but since it is very well known I suspect it will be overused as a subject and so I hope to find something more original. Thank you very much !

Comment: @Moo: these are exactly the types of systems I'm looking for! That is very helpful, thanks !